# Connection dropping when i plug an ethernet cable

Tags: windows-7, ethernet

Not sure if it belongs here, so please forgive me if it's not the right place.

On satuday, I installed a SSD on my desktop computer at my parents' place. Then, I reinstalled Windows on it.

The problem is that since I connected the ethernet cable to my computer, the connection has been dropping, going from 16 mb/s to 0, and sometimes the internet box would desynchronize.

I tried formatting every disk, reinstalled a fresh install of windows, but the connection still drops as soon as I turn on the computer (even when I'm on the bios).

Has anyone encountered this?

Edit: tried with another cable, tried with the same cable on another computer, it's not the problem.

Comment: Yes, you are right here. What internet box (router) do you use? Does it have several lan ports? Does it happen in every lan port?

Comment: I use a french provider called Free, and their router is called "Freebox". There are several lan ports, but if I plug the cable in one port, it works on my laptop but not on my desktop pc.

Comment: What is the speed seting for the lan adapter in windows? Auto or GBit? What happens when you change it to 100-Full Duplex?

Comment: I tried to change to all possible settings, didn't work. :(

Comment: Can you exchange date over the network using this adapter? If yes, nor more ideas, except testing another router.

Comment: I don't know what "exchange date" is :(  I think it's a hardware problem though, I'm going to buy a new network card and see if that solves the problem

Comment: Can you exchange data (files) over the network using this adapter? If yes, nor more ideas, except testing another router

Comment: Make sure the proper drivers are being used for the network card installed on the desktop. Also, ensure the BIOS date and time on the desktop are correct.

Comment: could it be drivers related since even when i'm in the bios, the connection drops ? Edit: BIOS date & time is OK.

Comment: Changed the network card, no difference.